# How do you add Java Based Spring config to an existing web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, web.xml

I have an existing web.xml and I am trying to add springs to a project.  I would like to use java based spring config: like the following.

```
AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(AppConfig.class);
```

However, I don't want a WebApplicationInitializer, because I don't want to rewrite the web.xml.

Is there way to reference the AppConfig.class from the web.xml? I don't want to define all my object in xml like old spring.

Thanks

Comment: I am confused. Do you like to modify the web.xml or not????

Comment: @Grim I was to modify the web.xml.  I don't want to replace it.

Comment: Is there a way to register the AppConfig in wab.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using spring (without spring-boot) there is a second path used by vintage programmers of old, an anicent and a forgotten path, by defining a `listener`. Scolls of new recommend a 3.0 servlet-api.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>aware.like.fox.crossing.water.AppConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

Old black, mighty magic.

Why do we change from xml to java. Xml is for configuration, java is for intelligence. We changed for false reasons or both is true?